# How to correctly calculate an orthographic projection matrix?

Tags: java, projection, orthographic

I've came across many different formulas how to build the projection matrix which all give different outputs, but i feel like I'm misunderstanding the concept. Currently I have this:

```
//x = 10 | y = 10 | width = 800 | height = 600
        float left = x;
        float top = y;
        float right = x + width;
        float bottom = y + height;

        final Matrix4f pMatrix = new Matrix4f();
        pMatrix.m[0][0] = 2f / (right - left);
        pMatrix.m[1][1] = 2f / (top - bottom);
        pMatrix.m[2][2] = -2f / (farZ - nearZ);
        pMatrix.m[3][0] = -(right + left) / (right - left);
        pMatrix.m[3][1] = -(top + bottom) / (top - bottom);
        pMatrix.m[3][2] = -(farZ + nearZ) / (farZ - nearZ);
        pMatrix.m[3][3] = 1;
```

With the given output:

```
0.0025, 0.0, 0.0, -1.025
0.0, -0.0033333334, 0.0, 1.0333333
0.0, 0.0, -0.0068965517, -2.724138
0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0
```

However I'm not sure whether the `right` and `bottom` constant are x + width & y + height or simply width & height? In some articles on the web people use different formulas using both.

Comment: That looks right, but you can double check on this [great tutorial](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html). Are you using OpenGL or DirectX? (It makes a minor difference to the Z component).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right and Bottom, in this calculation, should be absolute - that is, `right = x + width`. Your calculation looks correct. The main hint is lines like this one:

```
pMatrix.m[0][0] = 2f / (right - left);
```

The x component is being scaled by the width of the screen. Now, with your current setup, `right - left` is the same as `(x + width) - x`. That's definitely going to give `width`. If instead, you used `right = width`, then the calculation would become `width - x`, which makes very little sense.